# Sphere And A Ball

Tags: general-topology

A n-Sphere is defined as $$S^n=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}: ||x||=r\}$$

So if I look for example on a 2 dimensions ball it has a sphere of 1 dimension, why the sphere has one dimension less than the ball? as the sphere is "living" in the same 2 dimension "world" as the ball

Comment: Surely you would consider a plane $2$-dimensional, even if it "lives" in a three-dimensional world, wouldn't you?

Comment: I think I got it, we have one less dimension, because unlike the ball the sphere points/coordinates "can't move" on the radius

Comment: Exactly. Only the tangential directions are "available" in the sphere.

Comment: It is not a proof. But since the sphere $\mathbb{S}^n$ is the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^n$, it would be silly to have dimension different from that of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Of course, general topology never cease to amaze me. I would love to hear a counter-example if there is any...

Answer (score 0):

A sphere usually refers to the surface only, where a ball usually refers to the space contained inside the surface.